# Global variable causes script crash

Tags: javascript

If I add this above my JavaScript, my whole document won't work. If it's inside of a function it does work.

```
var items = document.getElementById('list').getElementsByTagName('LI');
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/sozhuqL1/1/

Comment: Then better put it inside of that function.

Comment: What is your question? You seem to know the solution already.

Comment: @Bergi But I need it in many functions. Why can't I just declare it globally?

Comment: You haven't asked a question here, simply made a statement.  You have not listed the error you are receiving, or provided a sufficient example.  The fiddle you provided doesn't demonstrate the problem, it simply lists the same code you listed here.

Comment: Probably because when you [execute the assignment too early](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element), it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

That is because that line of code is throwing an error. If it is not in the scope of a function it will be executed as soon as the page, script file with that line loads. Since i think that line is in-correct, it throws an error, and halts your entire page execution. If you open firebug, chrome tools you will see the error in the console/error log.